# Let LED blink for dot or dash in morse

Tags: python, led, morse-code, esp32

Using a ESP32 with python, this is my script. What it does is you can fill in some text and it will convert that to morse code and display it. But I also want the led to blink a second when it's a dash and 0,25 of a second when it's a dot.

With the script shown down below I get one blink. I think it's because of the `pattern.match`. I tried `find()` and `findall` but then I get these outputs

```
import morse
Enter sentence: hi

.... ..
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "morse.py", line 82, in <module>
AttributeError: 'ure' object has no attribute 'findall'
```

and

```
import morse
Enter sentence: hi
.... ..
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "morse.py", line 82, in <module>
AttributeError: 'ure' object has no attribute 'find'
```

*the script itself*

```
import time
from machine import Pin
led=Pin(5,Pin.OUT)
BRate=0.25

import re

def morse_dash():
    led.value(1)
    time.sleep(4*BRate)
    led.value(0)
    time.sleep(BRate)

def morse_dot():
    led.value(1)
    time.sleep(BRate)
    led.value(0)
    time.sleep(BRate)

CODE = {' ': '_', 
"'": '.----.', 
'(': '-.--.-', 
')': '-.--.-', 
',': '--..--', 
'-': '-....-', 
'.': '.-.-.-', 
'/': '-..-.', 
'0': '-----', 
'1': '.----', 
'2': '..---', 
'3': '...--', 
'4': '....-', 
'5': '.....', 
'6': '-....', 
'7': '--...', 
'8': '---..', 
'9': '----.', 
':': '---...', 
';': '-.-.-.', 
'?': '..--..', 
'A': '.-', 
'B': '-...', 
'C': '-.-.', 
'D': '-..', 
'E': '.', 
'F': '..-.', 
'G': '--.', 
'H': '....', 
'I': '..', 
'J': '.---', 
'K': '-.-', 
'L': '.-..', 
'M': '--', 
'N': '-.', 
'O': '---', 
'P': '.--.', 
'Q': '--.-', 
'R': '.-.', 
'S': '...', 
'T': '-', 
'U': '..-', 
'V': '...-', 
'W': '.--', 
'X': '-..-', 
'Y': '-.--', 
'Z': '--..', 
'_': '..--.-'}

def convertToMorseCode(sentence):
    sentence = sentence.upper()
    encodedSentence = ""
    for character in sentence:
        encodedSentence += CODE[character] + " " 
    return encodedSentence

while True:

    sentence = input("Enter sentence: ")
    encodedSentence = convertToMorseCode(sentence)
    print(encodedSentence)
    pattern = re.compile('.')
    if pattern.match(encodedSentence):
        [morse_dot() for _ in range(1)]
    else:
        [morse_dash() for _ in range(1)]
```

Comment: The regular expression `.` matches any character—which includes both a dot and a dash.

Comment: More to the point, why would you use a regex at all just to check a match for a single character?" Why are you uisng list comprehensions to call a function one time and build a one-element list that you ignore? How are you expecting to get anything _more_ than one blink if you don't loop over `encodedSentence`?

Comment: To be honest, I just started using Python. I don't know a lot about it so i'm making a lot of mistakes I guess. Because I couldn't figure it out I thought I'd ask here for some help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need regular expressions

```
import time
from machine import Pin
led=Pin(5,Pin.OUT)
BRate=0.25


def morse_dash():
    led.value(1)
    time.sleep(4*BRate)
    led.value(0)
    time.sleep(BRate)

def morse_pause():
    time.sleep(BRate)

def morse_dot():
    led.value(1)
    time.sleep(BRate)
    led.value(0)
    time.sleep(BRate)

CODE = {' ': '_', 
"'": '.----.', 
'(': '-.--.-', 
')': '-.--.-', 
',': '--..--', 
'-': '-....-', 
'.': '.-.-.-', 
'/': '-..-.', 
'0': '-----', 
'1': '.----', 
'2': '..---', 
'3': '...--', 
'4': '....-', 
'5': '.....', 
'6': '-....', 
'7': '--...', 
'8': '---..', 
'9': '----.', 
':': '---...', 
';': '-.-.-.', 
'?': '..--..', 
'A': '.-', 
'B': '-...', 
'C': '-.-.', 
'D': '-..', 
'E': '.', 
'F': '..-.', 
'G': '--.', 
'H': '....', 
'I': '..', 
'J': '.---', 
'K': '-.-', 
'L': '.-..', 
'M': '--', 
'N': '-.', 
'O': '---', 
'P': '.--.', 
'Q': '--.-', 
'R': '.-.', 
'S': '...', 
'T': '-', 
'U': '..-', 
'V': '...-', 
'W': '.--', 
'X': '-..-', 
'Y': '-.--', 
'Z': '--..', 
'_': '..--.-'}

def convertToMorseCode(sentence):
    sentence = sentence.upper()
    encodedSentence = ""
    for character in sentence:
        encodedSentence += CODE[character] + " " 
    return encodedSentence

while True:

    sentence = input("Enter sentence: ")
    encodedSentence = convertToMorseCode(sentence)
    print(encodedSentence)
    for i in encodedSentence:
        if i == ".":
            morse_dot()
        elif i == "-":
            morse_dash()
        else:
            morse_pause()
```